# Prevent deleting files downloaded with DownloadManager on app uninstall

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I've noticed that files downloaded using [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) get deleted if my app gets uninstalled.

Is there a way to prevent this?

**Update:**

Here is kotlin code that I use to enqueue download:

```
val downloadId = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(downloadUrl)).run {
    setTitle(title)
    setDescription(title)
    setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE)
    setAllowedOverMetered(true)
    setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
    setDestinationUri(file)
    downloadManager.enqueue(this)
}
```

... where `file` is of the form: `/storage/<sdcard-id>/Movies/<filename>.mp4`

Comment: To which location are they downloaded? And Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps I am experiencing this on Android N. I am saving files to `Movies` folder on sdcard.

Comment: To Movies folder of a removable micro sd card? And what would be full path?

Comment: @blackapps The folder (as output by third party file explorer) is: `/storage/<sdcard-id>/Movies`. I am 90% sure that I have created this folder at some point on my sdcard (so this is probably not standard folder managed by android). BTW, when I delete app only files that were downloaded through it get deleted. Rest of the files in the folder remain.

Comment: @blackapps just checked (with debugger) what actual path is used in `setDestinationUri` when building `DownloadManager.Request`. It is, as I've said above: `/storage/<sdcard-id>/Movies`.

Comment: On an Android N the removable micro sd card is not writable for apps. So your app will not have created that directory to begin with. You have any special device.? But DownloadManager can create a directory there and put files in it.

Comment: But... Ala.. What happens... I can only confirm what you said. The downloaded file disappeared. I bet you never read that in the docs... Me either. Did you check devices with other Android versions?

Comment: @blackapps (1) I have storage permissions granted to my app. (2) I meant that I have created `Movies` folder using third party file explorer, not my app.

Comment: @blackapps "Did you check devices with other Android versions?" - not yet.